# Eclipse hanging after changing code

Tags: android-emulator

I am using eclipse for Android, once I check my application it works fine. I just go back to home and run it again after some change and it shows "Launching project: 27%" and stays there forever until I close IDE and kill its instance from task manager and restart it. I don't know whats the reason. I've been using it since 4 to 6 months but its happening recently a couple of days before...
  Need help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also faced this issue..I just change my eclipse to latest version i.e **eclipse juno**  and this solves my problem.